# How do I open up the Scrapbook after saving something off the web in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-extensions

I have the Firefox addon Scrapbook and have saved a site to my hard drive. How do I navigate to the site now that I have saved it, I cant find the link anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot from the add-on page shows a ScrapBook sidebar:

[image]

So press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to display the FF menu, then check under `View / Sidebar` or `View / Toolbars` or even under the `Tools` menu for the relevant option to display the ScrapBook sidebar.

Edit: As per [this page](http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/feature2.php?lang=en), you can access it via:

- Clicking [image] in Firefox toolbar
- Firefox menubar, [View] > [Sidebar] > [ScrapBook]
- Firefox menubar, [ScrapBook] > [Show in Sidebar]
- Keyboard shortcut, Alt + K

Comment: You are a life saver. Amazing. You can add to your answer that after the clicking the Alt key it shows you that Alt K is the shortcut for Scrapbook. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, your comment is visible to everyone, so the extra info. you provided can be easily seen by other readers. :)

Comment: Cheerio ;) (15 Chars)